# Key field to save value to shared preferences

Tags: java, android

What is a good way to choose the "key" value when I save View value to shared preferences?

```java
 sPref = getSharedPreferences("Settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("R.id.CashButton",CashButton.isChecked());
        ...
        ed.commit();
```

For now I'm using the same Key like the "R" path.
But then if I decide to change my view id I should refactor my code by myself because Android Studio won't find this usage as a string.

Comment: create static strings inside your class. static final String MY_KEY = "my_key";

Comment: My goal was to reach good code readability that's why i wanted to use the "key" the same like view id's . If i will make  static sting it does not thange anything. Lets say i have view id "R.id.Exit" and static key string "Exit" then i decided to change to "R.id.SaveAndExit" but my static key field stay "Exit" and i need to correct it by my self if i want to be them the same. Thats why i start to search for some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a good practice to set this way.

This is primarily an opinion based question, but if, you need the view id to be the key, then I could suggest an alternative.

Create a hashmap and store a static string key and map it with the view ID. So that you need to change only the keys.

```
HashMap<Integer, String> mapIdToKey = new HashMap<>();
mapIdToKey.put(R.id.action_settings, "ActionSettingsKey");
.......
```

Use this as

```
sPref = getSharedPreferences("Settings",MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit()
ed.putBoolean(mapIdToKey.get(R.id.action_settings),CashButton.isChecked());
...
ed.commit();
```

Comment: Thank you for that exemple.

Comment: if this helps please accept the answer

@AndrewKubrik

Comment: If this is not good practice can you tell me what is the common way to chose key value. The static string in the class?

Comment: I said your method is not good. the method i suggested is comparatively safer.

best method is to create a class for constants and keys like 

`public class Keys {`

 `public static final String VIEW_ACTION_SETTINGS= "ActionSettingsKey"`; 
`}`

and use it like `Keys.VIEW_ACTION_SETTINGS`

Comment: would do with great pleasure but not enough reputation for the moment

Comment: @Andrew i upvoted your question, so you might got the reputation